# how can I pass a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem with this line of code

```
$db->select($tbl, plan_name,NULL,'plan_name ="{$pname}"');
```

see my dump of  the function

```
SELECT plan_name FROM plans WHERE plan_name ="{$pname}"
```

The variable $pname is passed as literal.

Comment: try this $db->select($tbl, plan_name,NULL,"plan_name ='{$pname}'");

Comment: @cartina This worked and here is my final code $db->select($tbl, plan_name,NULL,"plan_name='$pname'");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single-quote literals don't get variables replaced inside them.

For reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: ...and SQL literals **should never** get raw input replaced inside them anyway. The OP should switch to bound parameters to ensure the security of their application.

Comment: Good point, this vulnerability is also known as SQL injection and a websearch with that term will be enlightening.

Comment: @Jon How do I switch to bound parameters. Could you please help with an example.

Comment: @JOHNADAMU: Immediately to the right of this comment there is a "Related" section. Click the first question on the list.